# How can I handle multiple Firestore stream in a TabBarView?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

In my code, there is the main class that has 4 Tabs, now in the 3rd Tab there is 3 sub tab,

like Tab inside a Tab (this information may not be relative to the question) stil..

So, the Tab I am working on has 3 Tabs, captain, first officer and cabincrew, they all have individual stream from firestore, i get the stream and update the Ui as necessary however when i first load the tab it is fine but if i make some changes in firebase nothing gets updated, its not to do with `SetState` etc.. I am not getting the udpated data in the stream at all , I have added print statements for it.. No result.

this is the code so far

```
class _TrainingState extends State<Training> {
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _captainStream;
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _firstOfficerStream;
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> _cabinCrewStream;
  PlutoGridStateManager? _stateManager;
  List<String> cabinCrewKeys = [
    "NAME",
    "Annual (Recurrent)",
    "CRM",
    "DGR",
    "Med",
    "SMS",
    "Security"
  ];
  List<PlutoRow>? plutoRow;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _captainStream =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CAPTAIN_DATA').snapshots();
    _firstOfficerStream =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('FIRST_OFFICER_DATA').snapshots();
    _cabinCrewStream =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CABIN_CREW_DATA').snapshots();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Captain Training'),
                Tab(text: 'First Officer Training'),
                Tab(text: 'Cabin Crew Training'),
              ],
              indicatorColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 249, 4),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: _captainStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('data incoming...');
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      final data = snapshot.data!.docs
                          .map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
                          .toList();
                      return _buildGrid(data, "captain");
                    },
                  ),
                  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: _firstOfficerStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('data incoming...');
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      final data = snapshot.data!.docs
                          .map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
                          .toList();
                      return _buildGrid(data, "firstOfficer");
                    },
                  ),
                  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: _cabinCrewStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        print('data incoming...');
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      final data = snapshot.data!.docs
                          .map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
                          .toList();
                      return _buildGrid(data, "cabinCrew");
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Again, when I first run the app, I get the print statement inside the StreamBuilder , just not when i update something in the firebase, i need to reload the app or switch from Tabs to view the change.. What is wrong here ? why isn't it working?

Comment: I think to avoid this issue, you should directly use the stream returned by `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('CAPTAIN_DATA').snapshots()` inside each `StreamBuilder` instead of storing it in an instance variable. let me know if it work.

Comment: What are the changes that are you making in Firebase to update the streams.

Comment: Have you tried the above suggestions?

Comment: yea , this lets me know if there are changes in the firebase 
` if (snapshot.hasData) {
                for (var change in snapshot.data!.docChanges) {
                  if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
                  } else if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) {
                  } else if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.removed) {}
                }
              }` 
I had hoped that this would take care of it `return _buildGrid(data, "cabinCrew");` but it does not.

Comment: @Tayan i am just changing random values in collection to see if it will show in my app, ..update the ui etc

Comment: You have to send context for `_buildGrid` for observing changes. And you have to consume snapshot data  while mapping it. [example](https://codefile.io/f/eo5MchBAVx)